# Classic ASP migration to Windows 2016 Chilkat Zip Activex issue with temdir

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2016

This is as much a note for myself as to help anyone else.

We migrated a Classic ASP application to Window 2016. Everything worked in the end. Then an issue surfaced with some zip & download functionality for which we use a Zip component from Chilkat.

Initially, all looked well - the software component was installed and responded to instantiation, but the zip files did not appear on disk where expected.

What could it be? Modifying the code as:

```
Set oZip = Server.CreateObject(CHILLKAT_ZIP_OBJECT_NAME)
oZip.UnlockComponent(<the license code>) 
oZip.WriteZipAndClose()
Response.Write "<pre>" & Server.HTMLEncode( ozip.LastErrorText) & "</pre>"'
response.end
```

Produced

```
ChilkatLog:
  WriteZipAndClose:
    DllDate: Mar  1 2011
    UnlockPrefix: *******
    Username: *******
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: ActiveX
    tempFile: .\ckz_40NT.tmp
    Encryption: 0
    PasswordProtected: 0
    Failed to open file (2)
    filename: .\ckz_40NT.tmp
    currentWorkingDirectory: C:\Windows\SysWoW64\inetsrv
    osErrorInfo: Access is denied.
    Filename: .\ckz_40NT.tmp
    Failed to open output Zip file
    zipFilename: .\ckz_40NT.tmp
    Retrying with a new temp filename
    Encryption: 0
    PasswordProtected: 0
    Failed to open file (2)
    filename: .\ckz2_I473.tmp
    currentWorkingDirectory: C:\Windows\SysWoW64\inetsrv
    osErrorInfo: Access is denied.
    Filename: .\ckz2_I473.tmp
    Failed to open output Zip file
    zipFilename: .\ckz2_I473.tmp
    tempFileName: .\ckz2_I473.tmp
    Cannot open temporary file
    Failed.
```

What could the prolem be ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with chilkat's tempdir setting. On our version of Chilkat Tempdir defaulted to the IIS home folder which is unlikely ever to be happy having random files written to it. Adding a line to set tempdir to something more sensible, as below, cured the issue.

```
Set oZip = Server.CreateObject(CHILLKAT_ZIP_OBJECT_NAME)
oZip.UnlockComponent(<the license code>) 

' added the next line !
oZip.TempDir  = Server.MapPath("/some accessible folder path") 

oZip.WriteZipAndClose()
Response.Write "<pre>" & Server.HTMLEncode( ozip.LastErrorText) & "</pre>"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful info.  I'm a Classic ASP programmer and at some point will need to move from Windows 2012 to Windows 2016.   Been putting it off!

Comment: We are about 9 months in now and are not suffering any production issues except Windows 'randomly' keeps deciding to see one of the 3rd party components we use as a threat. We have a hunch this is to do with a threat profile update that Windows gets every other night, and some set of circumstances we have not yet pinned down. Needless to say, this was not an issue on 2008R2 or 2012, but then the black hats keep finding new exploits so we have to expect this kind of thing as MS tightens things up.

Comment: That's interesting!   I use a few components ( 3 or 4 I guess ).  Does that mean every so often one stops working and you need to reset something?   If it keeps happening that sounds a bit of a nightmare.  I run a website providing a web based service and can't afford constant downtime ( customers get uptight even with 30 mins downtime a month! )

Comment: Its a specific com component and to be fair its a few years old now and we should have upgraded it, but had to focus resource on other things. We are of course prioritising it now! We have maybe 10 com components like this and this is the only one. What happens is a process seems to lock the component in some kind of limbo. We have to use process explorer from sysinternals to search out the dllhost that is locking it and kill that. The site keeps on running while all this happens, but the feature that uses that locked dll fails. When we kill the process, the dll becomes usable again.